# Jupyter Lab Interactive plot: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FloatSlider' and 'float'

Tags: python, scipy, plotly, ipywidgets

I am following a video to learn how to use plotly to generate interactive plots, but I kept getting the error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FloatSlider' and 'float'.

I am pretty sure that the other parts are correct, the original tutor ran it well, yet on my jupyter lab, it runs into problem.

Here are the codes:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)

# Then layout the graph object in plotly
# Every object starts in a new line in the layout of plotly graph_objs
layout = go.Layout(
    # The title of the layout
    title = "Simple Example of Plotly",
    # Y axis, everything goes into a dict type, same of X axis
    yaxis = dict(
        title = "volts"
    ),
    xaxis = dict(
        title = "nanoseconds"
    )
)

# Now get a function with widgets using signals and frequency
# Put the trace into the function
def update_plot(signals, frequency):

    # Get a data list to put all traces in
    data = []
    for s in signals:
        # Put traces inside the function's loop
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x = x,
            n = freq * x,
            # Update y value using scipy's special's bessel functions
            y = special.jv(s, n),
            # Scatter has three modes, marker, lines, marker+lines
            mode = "lines",
            # Set a name
            name = "bessel {}".format(s),
            # Set up the interpolation, how the dots are connected with lines
            # line is going to be a dict
            line = dict(
                shape = "spline"
            )
        )
        data.append(trace1)

        # Plotting also goes in the function
        fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout=layout)
        # Finally show it
        py.offline.iplot(fig)

# Once the function is done, we create the widget
# Value in signals should be a tuple
signals = widgets.SelectMultiple(options = list(range(6)), value = (0,), 
description="Bessel Order")

# Make a freq
freq = widgets.FloatSlider(min = 1, max = 20, value = 1, description="Freq")

# Finally make the interaction
widgets.interactive(update_plot, signals = signals, frequency = freq)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? It seems that the special.jv(x,y) function doesn't accept operand *? But even I created another variable n = freq * x, it still reports error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you report an error in Python, you should include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in all that output, including exactly which line triggered the error.

Here, the line appears to be `n = freq * x`.  You created `freq` as `freq = widgets.FloatSlider(min = 1, max = 20, value = 1, description="Freq")`, so `freq` is a `FloatSlider` object.  The other operand, `x`, is a numpy array.  Apparently there is no multiplication operation defined for these operands.  That is, Python doesn't know how to multiply a `FloatSlider` and numpy array.

To get the actual value of the `FloatSlider` so you can do arithmetic with it, use the `value` attribute.  Change `n = freq * x` to

```
n = freq.value * x
```